# Where can I download animated gif that are designed for phone mobile applications?

Tags: animated-gif

I googled about `animated gif free download` but every site I opened are not good for mobile application. They are all suited for web pages and emails. So where can I download animated gif for these types of mobile application action : upload , download , exit , customers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the [sample canvas app](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) can help you.

Comment: in fact I am developing a j2me LWUIT mobile app. It is not facebook app. So what you gave is a more complex to me.